# Plotting of a polynomial function via two approaches

Tags: plotting, polynomials, coefficients

I am trying to plot a polynomial via two approaches:

1. Take CoefficientList of the polynomial and then take Internal`FromCoefficientList, and finally replacing the value of the free parameter with a numerical value.
2. Take the polynomial, replace the parameter with a numerical value, and then plot the resulting polynomial.

The two approaches should have given me the same plot. However when I try to check the plots, by using the following code:

```
Show[Plot[
  Internal`FromCoefficientList[
    CoefficientList[(1 - x) x (1 - (0.31875` (-1 + 2 x)^2)/(
        a (1 - x) x) + (0.050800781249999996` (-1 + 2 x)^4)/(
        a^2 (1 - x)^2 x^2) - (0.005397583007812499` (-1 + 2 x)^6)/(
        a^3 (1 - x)^3 x^3) + (0.0004301198959350585` (-1 + 2 x)^8)/(
        a^4 (1 - x)^4 x^4) - (
        0.000027420143365859977` (-1 + 2 x)^10)/(
        a^5 (1 - x)^5 x^5) + (1.4566951163113113`*^-6 (-1 + 2 x)^12)/(
        a^6 (1 - x)^6 x^6) - (6.63316526177472`*^-8 (-1 + 2 x)^14)/(
        a^7 (1 - x)^7 x^7) + (2.642901783988365`*^-9 (-1 + 2 x)^16)/(
        a^8 (1 - x)^8 x^8) - (9.360277151625461`*^-11 (-1 + 2 x)^18)/(
        a^9 (1 - x)^9 x^9) + (
        2.9835883420806145`*^-12 (-1 + 2 x)^20)/(
        a^10 (1 - x)^10 x^10)), {a, 1/a}], {a, 1/a}] /. a -> 0.6, {x, 
   0.1, 0.9}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[(1 - x) x (1 - (0.31875` (-1 + 2 x)^2)/(a (1 - x) x) + (
      0.050800781249999996` (-1 + 2 x)^4)/(a^2 (1 - x)^2 x^2) - (
      0.005397583007812499` (-1 + 2 x)^6)/(a^3 (1 - x)^3 x^3) + (
      0.0004301198959350585` (-1 + 2 x)^8)/(a^4 (1 - x)^4 x^4) - (
      0.000027420143365859977` (-1 + 2 x)^10)/(a^5 (1 - x)^5 x^5) + (
      1.4566951163113113`*^-6 (-1 + 2 x)^12)/(a^6 (1 - x)^6 x^6) - (
      6.63316526177472`*^-8 (-1 + 2 x)^14)/(a^7 (1 - x)^7 x^7) + (
      2.642901783988365`*^-9 (-1 + 2 x)^16)/(a^8 (1 - x)^8 x^8) - (
      9.360277151625461`*^-11 (-1 + 2 x)^18)/(a^9 (1 - x)^9 x^9) + (
      2.9835883420806145`*^-12 (-1 + 2 x)^20)/(
      a^10 (1 - x)^10 x^10)) /. a -> 0.6, {x, 0.1, 0.9}]]
```

the plots don't match.

The plot is as follows:
[image]

If anyone can clarify the issue, I would be thankful.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use both $a$ and $1/a$ in `CoefficientList`. Let's take a more simple example, which throws an error message together with a nonsensical result:

```
CoefficientList[1/a + a, {a, 1/a}]
(* CoefficientList::poly: 1/a+a is not a polynomial. *)
(* {{1/a}, {1}} *)
```

However, weirdly, the error will not be raised if only $1/a$ is present:

```
CoefficientList[a, {a, 1/a}]
(* CoefficientList::poly: a is not a polynomial. *)
(* {{1/a}} *)

CoefficientList[1/a, {a, 1/a}]
(* {{0}, {1}} *)
```

I cannot really explain this behaviour, but the overall solution to your problem is to use only $1/a$ as a variable, because you don't really have any $a$ terms in your polynomial.

```
p = (1 - x) x (1 - (0.31875` (-1 + 2 x)^2)/(a (1 - x) x) + 
    (0.050800781249999996` (-1 + 2 x)^4)/(a^2 (1 - x)^2 x^2) - 
    (0.005397583007812499` (-1 + 2 x)^6)/(a^3 (1 - x)^3 x^3) + 
    (0.0004301198959350585` (-1 + 2 x)^8)/(a^4 (1 - x)^4 x^4) - 
    (0.000027420143365859977` (-1 +  2 x)^10)/(a^5 (1 - x)^5 x^5) + 
    (1.4566951163113113`*^-6 (-1 + 2 x)^12)/(a^6 (1 - x)^6 x^6) - 
    (6.63316526177472`*^-8 (-1 + 2 x)^14)/(a^7 (1 - x)^7 x^7) + 
    (2.642901783988365`*^-9 (-1 + 2 x)^16)/(a^8 (1 - x)^8 x^8) - 
    (9.360277151625461`*^-11 (-1 + 2 x)^18)/(a^9 (1 - x)^9 x^9) + 
    (2.9835883420806145`*^-12 (-1 + 2 x)^20)/(a^10 (1 - x)^10 x^10));

Internal`FromCoefficientList[CoefficientList[p, 1/a], 1/a] == p // Reduce
(* True *)

Plot[{Internal`FromCoefficientList[CoefficientList[p, 1/a], 1/a] /. a -> 0.6,
      p /. a -> 0.6}, {x, 0.1, 0.9}]
```

[image: Plot]